# What is the word for the description below?

Tags: vocabulary

what is the word for domain in which the gun can shoot something?

For example, when a deer is 50 feet away and you can shoot it with a rifle, you say the deer is in what?

Answer (score 3):

the deer would be within range

Answer (score 0):

As previously aforementioned, usage of the term "range" would be an optimal reference. Hence, reusing the cited example, the dear would "be in shooting range".